# Issue is in calling JScript function

Tags: asp.net

I am using SpeechSynthesizer so convert from text to speech.

```
protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{

SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();
synth.Speak("Hello");

//JScript function call
Label1.Text = "<script type='text/javascript'>TestMethod();</script>";
}
```

In the above case, JScript method is not triggering. but with the same code if I comment synth.Speak("Hello"); its calling JScript method perfectly.

Can anybody tell why in above case JScript function is not triggering and may be alternative for same?

Comment: why you don not use ClientScriptManager.??

Comment: I have already tried ClientScriptManager as well, and got same result :(  --- Mahesh

Comment: use ClientScriptManager then inspect your page and tell me do you see your script on page source?

Comment: The speak method will be called on the server-side. It makes sense on Windows Apps, but not on Web apps. There are something wrong here.

Comment: yes, I can see my scripts in the page source.

Comment: Even then in that case, I tried to use async methods as well and calling JScript function on completed event. but same result ....

Comment: The async method would still be running in the server, just in a different thread. If you want to play audio in the user's browser, add the audio tag or a Windows Media Player/QuickTime Player on the page.

Comment: because i don't have SpeechSynthesizer i think i can not help you anymore . sorry

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

You could combine you javascript functionality by calling an [http handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) from inside your hjavascript function. You could also implement call a web service of some kind, either [REST](http://www.asp.net/web-api/tutorials/hands-on-labs/build-restful-apis-with-aspnet-web-api) or [SOAP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc302125.aspx). These server side services would contain your code behind functionality (for example SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer(); synth.Speak("Hello");).

Each of the above could be called using a javascript event (for example [onclick](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp)) registered on the specific html button, out of ASP.NET page lifecycle. For example you could call this function on the onclick event (`targetURL` would be replaced by the URL of http handler, or the respective service):

```
<button onclick="httpGetRequest('targetURL')">Click me</button>

function httpGetRequest(theUrl)
{

    //do something before code behind
    var xmlHttp = null;

    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false );
    xmlHttp.send( null );
    return xmlHttp.responseText;

    //do something after code behind
}
```

Hope I helped!

Comment: But I have to call 
SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();
synth.Speak("Hello");  before calling JScript function... How are you thinking to handle this....

Comment: I have tried to use WebMethod instead of HTTPHANDLERS but result is the same Not working :( and if I comment Speak method its working fine. I really don't have idea why after cpeak method there is problem calling JScript methods